# How to access Angular2 root injected Service in Component?

Tags: angular

According to http://victorsavkin.com/post/126514197956/dependency-injection-in-angular-1-and-angular-2, application-wide services can be added to the root injector using something like this:

```js
bootstrap(App, [UserService, LoginService]
```

And then can be accessed in child components like this:

```js
class A {
  constructor(userService: UserService) {
    
  }
}
```

However, an exception results, complaining the parameters can't be resolved and suggesting to make sure they have proper type or annotation.

What is the right way to inject application-wide services and access them in child components?

Comment: Correct TS syntax: `constructor(userService: UserService)` (i.e `(variable:Type)` )

Comment: @alexpods Thanks of pointing that out and yep, I know that. Sorry I dislexically swapped them in the question. But in my code the same exception is thrown. Any ideas why? I'm using jspm's in-line transpiler and have set the typescriptOptions: {"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true}

Comment: You've mistakenly changed `UserService`  to  `Userervice`. What about error: try `constructor(@Inject(UserService) userService: UserService)`. If it works then error is most likely somewhere in TS->JS transpilation.

Comment: Also if `A` doesn't have any decorators, you must mark it with `@Injectable` decorator. See [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4404)

Comment: I must have a transpiler issue then because while using @Inject() does not cause any exceptions, the UserService is not injected.

Comment: I try to explain some of this here: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.0

Comment: Having the same issue and looks like the VSCode is not able to detect the injected service at the time of boootstrap. After compiling I am getting 'Cannot read property 'query' of null'.

Answer (score 1):

If the child component is in a separate file, make sure you still import the service in.

```
import {UserService} from '../../services/UserService';

@Component({
     // don't add UserService in providers here
})

class A {
    userService: UserService;
    constructor(userService: UserService) { 
        this.userService = userService;
    }
}
```

Comment: This beats the whole purpose of sharing a single instance of service across the app.

Comment: No, it is the service provider that creates a new instance. Without using a provider in the current component, angular's injector will look to the parent component's injector and so on until it finds an instance (in our case, in the root level when we bootstrapped the application).

Docs: [Hierarchical DI](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html), 
[Providers](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#providers)